# Converting from List[String] to List[Int] based on Map

Tags: scala

Trying to convert `List[String]` into `List[Int]` based on a `Map`.
However if the key does not exist I will get a null pointer exception.
How to handle that?

```
val strList = ["a","b","not exist in map" ]
val myMap =  Map(
    "a" -> 1,
    "b" -> 2
  )

var myList = new ListBuffer[Int]()
    strList.foreach(k =>
      myList += myMap(k)
      
    )

  myList.toList
```

Comment: To which int do you want to convert strings that are not in the map?

Comment: Please read the **Scaladoc** you do not need to be mutable for something like this. You can do this: `val intList = strList.map(s => myMap.get(x))` which will return a **List** of **Options** which represent that some values do not exists so you can deal with that latter, you can also do this: `val intList = strList.map(x => myMap.getOrElse(key = x, default = 0))` if you wan to provide a default value _(in this case zero, but you can use what you want)_ for missing keys. Or if you want to remove / skip missing values do `val intList = strList.flatMap(x => myMap.get(x))`.

Comment: use filter `myMap.filter(x=>strList.contains(x._1)).map(_._2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assumes that any `List` entry that isn't a `Map` key should just be ignored.

```
val strList = List("a", "b", "not exist in map")
val myMap   = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)

val myList = strList.flatMap(myMap.get)
//myList: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

The order of results, `myList`, is determined by the order of keys found in `strList`.

Comment: works great . Flatmap will ignore if certain element not exists. Will not give any error ?

Comment: `flatMap()` will "flatten" a list of `Option`s into a list of elements.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution works perfectly, but for completeness I'd like to add the following:

```
val strSet = Set("a", "b", "not exist in map")
val myMap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3)

val myList = myMap.view.filterKeys(strSet).values.toList
//myList: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

This solution's complexity is linear with respects to the number of items in the map, whereas `strList.flatMap(myMap.get)` is linear with respects to the number of items in the list.

Note that I used a `Set` instead of a `List`, otherwise the complexity would have been quadratic. Note further that I used the set itself as a predicate (more about it in the Scala API docs, [here for version 2.13.4](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html#apply(elem:A):Boolean)).

You can play around with this solution [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/1gSAaU1ySaaiEToXLWwjLg/11).

Comment: Thank you so much.